# Does GCP Load Balancer limits the data size during post?

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I'm facing issues with posting data to instance in Google Compute Engine. I have tested using httpbin and am able to push over 1mb of data if I connect to the instance directly. However, when connecting with a https load balancer in front, I can't push over 300kb of data.

Comment: What was the error you get?